# why the const function returns lvalue rather than rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, rvalue, lvalue

The `ff()` function returns a rvalue but when I change the return value of function  to be `const`, does it return lvalue? Why does the following output change its output from `"lvalue reference"` to `"rvalue reference"` when I change  `test ff() { }` into `const test ff() { }`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class test { };
void fun( const test& a)
{
    cout << "lvalue reference"<<endl;
}
void fun(  test&& a)
{
    cout << "rvalue reference"<<endl;
}
const test ff() { } // <<---return value is const now
int main()
{

  fun(ff());
}
```

Output:

```
lvalue reference
```

Comment: C++ can't implicitly remove the const.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`void fun(  test&& a)` is a function that takes a reference to a non-const rvalue.  `ff` returns a `const test` which is a const rvalue.  You cannot bind a reference to a non-const rvalue to a const rvalue as that would violate const-correctness.  This is why it instead binds to `void fun( const test& a)`, which takes a reference to a `const test`

---

Do note that when returning by value there is no benefit to return a `const thing` over a `thing`.  The only time adding `const` to the return type matters is when returning by reference. If you have a member function that is marked as `const` or returning a reference to a constant data member then you must use `const` to preserve const-correctness.

Comment: I think it is much improved.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks for the feedback

Comment: You are welcome.  Thanks for the update; `const value foo()` functions are a (teeny tiny) scourge.

Answer (score 2):

Your test function output is misleading and test functions should be instead:

```
void fun( const test& a)
{
    cout << "lvalue const reference"<<endl;
}
void fun( test& a)
{
    cout << "lvalue reference"<<endl;
}
void fun(  test&& a)
{
    cout << "rvalue reference"<<endl;
}
void fun( const test&& a)
{
    cout << "rvalue const reference"<<endl;
}
```

then you will see what is really happening there.

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this where you're interested in why the compiler chose one overload instead of another, it's often easiest to (more or less) ask the compiler directly how/why it made the decision it did, by only allowing it to select the other function, and seeing what error message it gives (or whether it may give no error message at all). In this case, we can remove the function taking a const lvalue reference to get code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class test { };
// void fun( const test& a)
// {
//     cout << "lvalue reference"<<endl;
// }
void fun(  test&& a)
{
    cout << "rvalue reference"<<endl;
}
const test ff() { } // <<---return value is const now
int main()
{

  fun(ff());
}
```

Now if we try to compile, the compiler will directly tell us why the remaining function wasn't selected:

```
trash9.cpp:16:3: error: no matching function for call to 'fun'
  fun(ff());
  ^~~
trash9.cpp:8:6: note: candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const test') would lose const qualifier
void fun(  test&& a)
     ^
```

That's not as authoritative as a direct quote from the standard, but compilers are good enough at things like this that the error messages can be fairly informative.